# Login using mysqli goes worng when incerting values through bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

so I want to make a simple login and it works but when I use bind_param, it always shows 0 rows.

Here is the code:

```
session_start();
include("config.php");
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='?' AND password LIKE SHA1('?')")) {

    $sql->bind_param('ss',$email, $password);

    $sql->execute();

    $sql->store_result();

    $num = $sql->num_rows;

    $sql->close();

    if($num>0){
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

I confirmed that I receive both email and password fields but the query only gets results when I manually enter them instead of "?" and removing bind_param.

I know that it is simple, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `'?'`: that's not a parameter, it's a literal `?`.

Comment: I need to use '?' or else the query won't work ;)

Comment: have you tried `$password = sha1($_POST['password']);` then in your query `... AND password LIKE ?`

Comment: from php.net `Note: Secure password hashing
It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm.` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

Comment: I've rollbacked your edit with the "solution" so further readers who come here in the future are not mislead. Several people have told you that you simply need to remove the quotes, yet you've decided that you are not allowed to use e-mails or SQL functions together with bind parameters.

Answer (score 1):

remove quotes from ?
it'll not be working with quotes...
You can check some examples here,
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Quotes shouldn't be there. check some examples on above link.

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quotes from ?,

```
 if ($sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='Th3lmuu90@gmail.com' AND password LIKE SHA1(?)")) {

    $sql->bind_param('s', $password);
```

Instead of LIKE SHA(?),

you can use check,

```
   $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='Th3lmuu90@gmail.com' AND password = SHA1(?)");
```

Comment: ? parameter doesn't require quotes th3lmuu90. Ref -link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @Th3lmuu90 - if you've solved this yourself, could you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look carefully at the [usage example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#example-1675):

```
$mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")
                                                       ^
```

If you quote the place-holder, it no longer has any special meaning: it becomes a literal question mark.

Answer (score 0):

first use

```
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
```

then use

```
... AND password LIKE ?...
```

Comment: Why are common hashing functions such as md5() and sha1() unsuitable for passwords?
Hashing algorithms such as MD5, SHA1 and SHA256 are designed to be very fast and efficient. With modern techniques and computer equipment, it has become trivial to "brute force" the output of these algorithms, in order to determine the original input.

Because of how quickly a modern computer can "reverse" these hashing algorithms, many security professionals strongly suggest against their use for password hashing.

Comment: above taken from - http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

Comment: What I mean is that `LIKE SHA1(?)` should work just fine. Nothing prevents you from using place-holders as function parameters.

Comment: The problem was the quotes around it, making the question mark a literal question mark, as the argument kept going around in circles I bypassed the need for the argument and moved the `sha1()` outside the query